# Can reduction formula be applied on $\int \cos^n x \: dx$ when n is a negative integer?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, recurrence-relations, indefinite-integrals

The reduction formula for integration of $\cos^n x$ is:

> $$
> \int \cos^n x \: dx=\frac1n \cos^{n-1} x\sin x+\frac{n-1}n  \int \cos^{n-2} x \: dx 
> $$

But if $n$ is a negative integer like $-1, -2,-3,\ldots $ then can this reduction formula still be applied?

Comment: See [Wallis' integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals).

Answer (score 3):

You may read the relation
$$
\int \cos^n x \: dx=\frac1n \cos^{n-1} x\sin x+\frac{n-1}n  \int \cos^{n-2} x \: dx \tag1
$$ in the form
$$
\int \cos^{n-2} x  \: dx=-\frac1{n-1} \cos^{n-1} x\sin x+\frac n{n-1}  \int \cos^{n} x \: dx. \tag2
$$ Then, for negative integers like $n=-1, -2,-3,\cdots, $ by a recurrence, you will end up with considering
$$
 \int \cos^{-2} x \: dx \quad \text{or} \quad  \int \cos^{-1} x \: dx. \tag3
$$

---

Two examples.

We just use $(2)$.

> $$
> \begin{align}
> \int \cos^{-4} x  \: dx=\int \cos^{-2\color{red}{-2}} x  \: dx&=\frac13 \cos^{-3} x\sin x+\frac 23  \int \cos^{-2} x \: dx\\\\
> &=\frac13 \cos^{-3} x\sin x+\frac 23  \tan x +C
> \end{align}
> $$

and

> $$
> \begin{align}
> \int \cos^{-3} x  \: dx=\int \cos^{-1\color{red}{-2}} x  \: dx&=\frac12 \cos^{-2} x\sin x+\frac 12  \int \cos^{-1} x \: dx\\\\
> &=\frac12 \cos^{-2} x\sin x+\frac 12   \log \left|\tan (x/2+\pi/4)\right| +C
> \end{align}
> $$

Comment: Doesn't that setup a direct relation between secant and cosine reduction?

Comment: Please, I don't understand the question.